# Best resources to learn C/C++

Tags: java, c++, c

I am mostly a javascript/jquery developer programming UI/UX experiences but I want to learn more about other languages such as C/C++ and I am not really sure where to start...

Do I learn Java first?  I don't know!  I was wondering what the best way to go about this was?

Comment: If C++, pick the book from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: I'm not sure why I was down voted for asking a question about learning?  Lame.

Comment: There are down votes because you didn't research first.  There are very many articles on StackOverflow relating to "where should I start learning" or "how should I start learning".  I suggest you first learn how to research.

Comment: The point of this site is to ask questions.  I have concluded my own research and wanted to make sure I was attempting to learn the correct thing.  For you to say that I should "learn how to research" is insulting.  I suggest you learn how to be a decent member of this community and not put people down for asking questions.  Totally uncalled for.

Answer (score 3):

Don't learn Java first. It's a completely different language which aims at different types of applications. Just read a C++ book, that will do it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you gonna do with it. I think for desktop programming and for games is c/c++ better because of performance and if whant to develop cross-plattform software you might be better suited with java. And for web programming it might better to use Java. Java is more secure because of it's sandboxed architecture. Java was developed with secure in mind as they say :).

To learn c/c++ check the following URL: cplusplus.com

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Java to jump in if you know javascript. You got the syntax basics. See http://www.learncpp.com/ for learning c++

Comment: I understand this, I am just trying to see what would be the best way to learn more about other languages that aren't client side.